# Can't declare Q_ENUM from an enum defined in another class

Tags: c++, qt

[This documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_ENUMS) states

> If you want to register an enum that is declared in another class, the enum must be fully qualified with the name of the class defining it. In addition, the class defining the enum has to inherit QObject as well as declare the enum using Q_ENUMS().

However I can't make this work, in the following example.

Class A:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include <classb.h>

class ClassA : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_ENUMS(ClassB::TestEnum)

public:
   explicit ClassA(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
   {
      const QMetaObject *metaObj = this->metaObject();
      qDebug() << metaObj->enumeratorCount();
   }
};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

ClassB:

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QObject>

class ClassB : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_ENUMS(TestEnum)

public:
   enum TestEnum { A, B, C };

   explicit ClassB(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent)
   {
      const QMetaObject *metaObj = this->metaObject();
      qDebug() << metaObj->enumeratorCount();
   }
};

#endif // CLASSB_H
```

main:

```
#include <classa.h>
#include <classb.h>

int main() 
{
   ClassA objectA;
   ClassB objectB; 
}
```

Expected output:

1

1

Actual Output:

0

1

Comment: The documentation states this a second time with example: "Had the enumeration type been declared in another class, its fully qualified name (i.e., OtherClass::Priority) would be required, and that other class would also have to inherit QObject and register the enumeration type there using the Q_ENUMS() macro.". Maybe a bug? Don't you get any MOC warnings or errors?

Comment: this is not needed. Once you have meta data for this enumeration in class `ClassB` this meta data can be used anywhere, you don't have to regenerate meta data in another class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a summary of a little research:

- Information stated in the documentation about registration of a enum declared in another class looks outdated.
- `Q_ENUMS(Class::EnumName` doesn't create a new enumerator, and useless.
- When you declare a new `Q_PROPERTY` in ClassA you should use full form of the enum `ClassB::EnumName`.
- As soon as `EnumName` is registered in ClassB it doesn't need to be registered any more.
- A property created using a enumerator from another class works correctly.

  ```
  class ClassA : public QObject
  {
  public:
   Q_OBJECT       
   Q_PROPERTY(ClassB::TestEnum test READ test)

  public:
  explicit ClassA(QObject *parent = 0)
  {
      const QMetaObject *metaObj = this->metaObject();
      qDebug() << metaObj->enumeratorCount();

      QMetaProperty property = metaObj->property(metaObj->indexOfProperty("test"));
      if (property.isEnumType())
      {
          const QMetaEnum& enumerator = property.enumerator();

          qDebug() << enumerator.name();

          for (int i = 0 ; i < enumerator.keyCount(); i++)
          {
              qDebug() << QLatin1String(enumerator.key(i)) <<  enumerator.value(i);           
          }
      }
  }
  ClassB::TestEnum test() const
  {
      return ClassB::A;
  }
  };
  ```

Output:

```
0 
TestEnum 
"A" 0 
"B" 1 
"C" 2
```

Comment: Maybe you should report this documentation inconsistency to the Qt bug tracker.