# enum type as property type in C++ class for QML

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qml

I have the similar situation as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25795238/cant-declare-q-enum-from-an-enum-defined-in-another-class). However I use the property in QML widgets. I am successful to register my class with enum (using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`) and I can do the following:

```
console.log(ClassB.A) // return me an integer
```

Unfortunately when I take the property in QML

```
console.log(myAObjfromCpp.test) // I get QVariant(ClassB::TestEnum)
```

And those two return value are not comparable with each other. How properly create a property from cpp of enum type defined in a another class and use it in QML?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089196/how-to-access-c-enum-from-qml/20108038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained in the docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#enumeration-types).

As per it you need to use declare it using `Q_ENUMS`.
For eg.:

```
//C++ code
Q_ENUMS(Status)
Q_PROPERTY(Status status READ status NOTIFY statusChanged)

enum Status {
    Ready,
    Loading,
    Error
};

//QML code
console.log(Message.Ready) //Message being the class in which enum is defined
```

Comment: don't use Q_ENUMS in Qt5 there is Q_ENUM for replacement

Comment: Qt 5.5 and greater to be precise.

Comment: @astre This is pretty well know and works for me. I have asked how to do that if enum is defined in another class. I have a problem with this case.